# JSF Converter for non-persisted entity

Tags: jsf, converters, selectonemenu

I have a JSF converter with the following method:

```
@Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

        Actor a = getEjbCasos().getActorByName(value);        
        return a;
    }
```

This is called from a SelectOneMenu:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="actores" value="#{crearCasosBean.currentActor}">
   <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true"/>
   <f:selectItems value="#{crearCasosBean.actorRows}" var="actor" itemLabel="#{actor.name}" itemValue="#{actor}"/>   
   <f:converter binding="#{actorConverter}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Instead of selecting an actor, the user can enter new actor names, which creates a new Actor entity but does not persist it to the database.  This Actor name is then added to the actorRows list so that it can be selected next time.

The problem I'm having is that since the Actor the user has created has not been persisted to the database, when they select this Actor the converter returns null.  I'm not sure how to tell the converter that this reference should be the same as the first Actor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) `SelectItemsConverter` for this. It converts the submitted value directly based on the available values in `<f:selectItems>` by default via object's `toString()` representation. So if you can guarantee that you can provide an unique `toString()` representation, then this converter should just do it. Additional bonus is that this converter don't hit the DB at all.

After dropping OmniFaces JAR in the webapp's runtime classpath, it's just a matter of

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
```

without any additional configuration or code. See also [the showcase example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter).